# Rails paths from url_helpers are different from view paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, urlhelper

In my Rails 4 application I have a model that needs to build links to other parts of the application. I am using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.<path_name>` to generate the URL of this link. The problem I have is that this generated path doesn't included the nested path.

Locally the app is served to `localhost:3000` and all the paths work correctly, but when I deploy to a remote server it is served by Nginx/Passenger using the root `http://<servername>/admin` and the paths are incorrect. So as an example, what I want is `payments_path` to resolve to `"/admin/payments"`, but instead I get `"/payments"`.

The strange thing is when I use `payments_path` directly in my view or other places in my app, I get the path with the nested `/admin` path, ie `"/admin/payments"`.

Anyone have any idea why path is giving me two different things in the view and the `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`?

Comment: What about `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.admin_payments_path`?

Comment: NoMethodError for `admin_payments_path`

Comment: Can you show us your routes file? What Sergio's posted should be correct

Comment: Relevant line in routes.rb, `resources :payments`. Not doing anything weird there. Why would admin be prepended to the path name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core issue is that path generation at the view / controller level is getting some additional metadata to generate the paths correctly. I ended up finding a [blog post dealing with the subject of routes inside models](http://hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/).

The author of the blog (Adam Hawkins) recommends the following approach for adding paths generation as a concern to the model,

```
module Routing
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  included do
    def default_url_options
      ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
    end
  end
end

class UrlGenerator
  include Routing
end
```

This concern piggybacks off the ActionMailer configuration, which in my case is,

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://dev.<domain-name>.com/admin' }
```

However after I added this concern I still couldn't generate the full relative path, but I could get the absolute url generation working. So I ended up using `payments_url` instead of `payments_path`.

I think there is probably a way to get relative paths to work, but this is my workaround for the time being.